# Dúvida sobre relacionamento entre tabelas no mysql

Tags: mysqli

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

1. Tabela: Clientes
2. Tabela: Interesses do cliente
3. Tabela: Usuário

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na tabela interesses do cliente, eu preciso inserir o id do usuário e o id do cliente como chaves estrangeiras, o id do usuário eu vou pegar de uma session.

Preciso saber, se quando criado o relacionamento com o respectivos índices, o id do cliente é inserido dinamicamente na tabela interesses do cliente como chave estrangeira?

Comment: Se você não criar um [gatilho](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) ou [procedimento](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) no banco, não. A restrição serve como limitador daquele campo aceitar apenas dados contidos na coluna da tabela a qual ele está sendo referenciado.

Comment: É por isso que uso frameworks como `Laravel 4`. Você provavelmente vai dar uma voltão pra fazer isso aí, amigo. Você provavelmente vai ter que fazer um `TRIGGER`

Answer (score 1):

Sua modelagem não está muito boa.

Não tem nenhuma ligação entre o cliente e o usúario, como você irá saber qual é o cliente somente pelo id do usuario.

Se cada cliente poder ter mais de um usúario, então crie uma tabela MxN entre as tabelas usúario e cliente, usuario_cliente e coloque somente o id_usuario na tabela de interesses, assim você ira conseguir consultar posteriormente qual cliente está vinculado ao interesse fazendo um INNER JOIN.

Agora se cada cliente tem apenas um usúario não vejo motivos de duas tabelas diferentes, crie apenas uma nesse caso.

Comment: Revisei minha modelagem, realmente estava sem muita lógica, os campos da tabela interesses_cliente eu migrei para a tabela clientes, deixando somente a tabela clientes e usuários e criando uma chave estrangeira na tabela clientes para o id do usuário.

Comment: Muito bom, uma boa modelagem é importante para o sistema.